# How to sample from a pandas without changing indexes and keep the remaining samples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have a Dataframe and I want to sample 20 percent of the data. However, my data is not balanced that's why I need to sample 20 percent of each category (20% positive, 20%negative and 20% neutral).

After sampling I want to save the rest of the data in a new Dataframe.

This is my data frame:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['hello', 'how', 'good', 'bad', 'ok', 'bye', 'ol'], 'Sentiment':[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2]})`

##sample 20% (for simplicity n=1) of the data based on the distribution in `sentiment column`:

`dfsample = df.groupby('Sentiment').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1))`

```
text    sentiment
hello.   0
how.     1
ol.      2
```

##keep the rest of the data:

`df_rest = df.loc[~df.index.isin(dfsample.index)]`

This `df_rest` will output the original `df` I had as the indexes in `df_sample` does not match the indexes in `df`.

The problem is that when we use `apply` the index will change and I cannot retrieve the remaining data.

I searched through the internet and learned that `transform` keeps the original index. But transform used to return one scaler value based on the group.

This is the ideal output in this simple example:

```
text    sentiment
good.    1
bad.     1
ok.      2
bye      0
```

Comment: You can potentially use pandas compare method to find the difference between two dataframes, something like: `df_rest = df.compare(dfsample)`. This should return the rows that are different between two dataframes.

Comment: @pavel thanks for the comment. I tried that but raises the error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Answer (score 1):

One easy approach is to use `train_test_split` from `sklearn` with `stratify` parameter:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, stratify=df[['Sentiment']])
```

Be aware here, that **the calculated size** of each subset (train and test) must be greater or equal to the number of classes (used for stratification).

Comment: I appreciate it you shared your solution with me. I am looking for a pandas way of doing this.